# elasticsearch run multiple different query in one call

Tags: angularjs, elasticsearch

I want to run 3 differents query (on the same index) with one call on elasticsearch service.

Is this possible ?

---

More elaborate question :

I make an autocomplete function in angularjs who search on 3 fields and display them :
"T_FAMILY" + "T_GENUS" + "T_SCIENTIFICNAME".

i was making only one query :

```
"query" : { "query_string" : { "query" : "T_FAMILY:" +value +" or T_GENUS:"+value+ " or T_SCIENTIFICNAME:"+value} }
// value is the user input and can contain wildcard *
```

but not revelant results.

Now i want to make 3 different query and sort each one by score. and finally get the 3 results and 
merge them in an array and sort by score (i do this by my addKeyword() function).

```
var keywords = [];
keywords.push(val);
$scope.isHide.logo=true;
return elasticQuery.search({
 index: $scope.domaine,
 size: 20,
 _source: false,
 body: {
    "fields" : ["T_FAMILY","T_GENUS","T_SCIENTIFICNAME"],
    "query": { "bool" : {"must" : [{"wildcard" : { "T_FAMILY" : val }}]}},
    "sort" : { "_score" : "desc" }
 }
}).then(function (response){
    addKeyword(response,keywords);
    return elasticQuery.search({
       index: $scope.domaine,
       size: 20,
       _source: false,
       body: {
          "fields" : ["T_FAMILY","T_GENUS","T_SCIENTIFICNAME"],
          "query": {"bool" : {"must" : [{"wildcard" : { "T_GENUS" : val }}]}},
          "sort" : { "_score" : "desc" }
       }
    }).then(function (response) {
       addKeyword(response,keywords);
       return elasticQuery.search({
          index: $scope.domaine,
          size: 20,
          _source: false,
          body: {
             "fields" : ["T_FAMILY","T_GENUS","T_SCIENTIFICNAME"],
             "query": {"bool" : {"must" : [{"wildcard" : { "T_SCIENTIFICNAME" : val }}]}},
             "sort" : { "_score" : "desc" }
          }
       }).then(function (response) {
          addKeyword(response,keywords);
          return keywords;
       });

       return keywords;
    });
});
```

I didn't find anything who help so i make 3 imbricated call of elastichsearch in my js code but it's not the best way maybe.

Thanks

Comment: You might be able to do something with aggregations. If your queries are simple, you can use a filter aggregation and combine it with a top hits sub aggregation for example. However, if you have three separate queries, it's probably best to fire all three of them separately. Also you can do this asynchronously in javascript.

Comment: usually scores across queries are  not comparable  so merging may not work as intended

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to run differents queries in elasticsearch with "dis_max" :

```
return elasticQuery.search({
     index: $scope.domaine,
     size: 20,
     _source: false,
     body: {
        //"min_score" : 0.50,
        "fields" : ["T_FAMILY","T_GENUS","T_SCIENTIFICNAME"],
        "highlight": {"pre_tags": ["<strong>"], "post_tags": ["</strong>"], "fields": { "T_FAMILY": {},"T_GENUS" : {}, "T_SCIENTIFICNAME": {} }},
        "query" : {
           "dis_max" : {
              "tie_breaker" : 0.0,
              "boost" : 1.0,
              "queries" : [
                 {"wildcard" : { "T_FAMILY" : val }},
                 {"wildcard" : { "T_GENUS" : val }},
                 {"wildcard" : { "T_SCIENTIFICNAME" : val }}
              ]
           }
        },
        "sort" : { "_score" : "desc" }
     }
  }).then(function (response){
    return addKeywords(response,keywords);
  });
```